# IIS anonymous vs windows authentications

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I'm trying to understand the IIS windows and anonymous authentications. is there any difference between below options,

1. Anonymous
2. Anonymous + windows

Answer (score 1):

**Anonymous authentication** gives users access to the public areas of your Web or FTP site without prompting them for a username or password. By default, the IUSR account, which was introduced in IIS 7.0 and replaces the IIS 6.0 IUSR_computername account, is used to allow anonymous access

**Windows authentication**, Identifies and authorizes users on the server's user list. Access to resources on the server is then granted or denied on the user account's privileges. Windows authentication is best suited for intranet web applications. The advantage of Windows authentication is that the web application can use the exact same security that applies to your corporate network. username, passwords, and permissions are the same for network resources and web applications

If both anonymous and windows authentication is enabled in IIS, and if we don't have a deny entry or anonymous in the web config then the resources on the web server are accessed using anonymous authentication

Comment: Cite your sources.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As long as anonymous authentication is enabled, IIS uses it, no matter whatever else you configure.